# Closing popup and other script on clicking close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm not great with Javascript and jquery etc.

Using http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ and a CSS popup, i'm trying to create a file upload that you can crop the image by choosing your selection with and then cancel or continue to upload the file.

I've got the popup opening with the image inside and you can crop the part of the image you want. My issue at the moment is that when you click on the "Cancel" button, the crop highlight still remains. How would I go about getting that to close too?

I've tried numerous things, checking to see if it can hide the div if the other div is pressed, or hidden, or not visible, and I just can't seem to get anything to work.

Here is my jsbin, the upload part isn't working though, so you can't actually see the error on there.

http://jsbin.com/eKaNupU/1

Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE:

Working (up until it doesn't!) example: http://www.costapass.es/imageupload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to do cancelSelection() (see: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html).

In order to get access that method you need to get a reference to your imgAreaSelect object. To do that, put the following in your `<head>` (or similar).

```
var ias = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  ias = $('#uploadPreview').imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
});
```

Then modify your close button to be:

```
  <div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" onclick="ias.cancelSelection();popup('popUpDiv'); ">Cancel</a>
    <img id="uploadPreview" style="display:none;"/>
  </div>
```

Your modified jsbin: http://jsbin.com/eKaNupU/11/edit

Comment: Still not showing on there. I will create an example on my hosting and upload it.

Comment: http://www.costapass.es/imageupload/

Here's a working(up until it doesn't!) example.

Comment: Spot on, thank you Don! Whilst we're on this subject(ish) rather than opening a new question... Do you know if it's possible to reset the file field once you cancel too? I'm using onchange="popup('popUpDiv')" to activate the popup, but if you cancel and then try to use the same image again, it's obviously not seeing it as a change. Would it be a case of giving the file field a null value when pressing the cancel button? Thanks again

Comment: You would have to wrap your form elements in a <form> tag and then call that form's reset(). See updated jsbin for the full picture.

Comment: Super, Smashing, Great. Thanks Don!